# can I be keylogged at pc lock-in?

Tags: keylogger

I was opening my pc with a password and noticed that the letters of the keystrokes did not appear in the password-field. It made me suspicious if a key-logger 'snatched' my password.
Opening the pc with a password is a spine reaction, so I went back to check how much would be needed to miss a proper lock-in .. I'm sure enough to proceed to question you here.
Would I in the first place notice, if someone used a keylogger on me? Is letters not appearing in the text-field symptomatic for the use of a key-logger against me? If yes, do I have any chance of finding the key-logger to delete it from my pc?
I've written plenty of appropriate code (opengl + glfw) to suggest, that the keylogger would have to work as a service (added with administrator-credintials?) and be turned on at pc-start to do it's job, but I don't have a clue more than that.

Answer (score 0):

> letters of the keystrokes did not appear in the password-field

It could be a scenario; maybe the textbox was out of focus while you were trying to login. Because I beleive that keylogger won't hinder the keypress of a textbox.

Comment: ups, my 'answer' above should have been a comment here - you must be right.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience of getting hardware-input it would seem to be a slim case not to reveal it in a stelthy situation - you must be right.